# Does the OWL API Support Oasis XML Catalogs?

Tags: java, owl-api

The OWL API provides several IRI mappers to cache ontology documents locally. Do any of them use Oasis XML Catalogs, as Protege does? Even better, is there one to automatically cache read-in ontologies locally and check the original IRI for updates before using the local copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Protege team have released the xmlcatalog component as a standalone (from the rest of Protege) module and it has an implementation of OWLOntologyIRIMapper:

https://github.com/protegeproject/xmlcatalog/blob/master/src/main/java/org/protege/xmlcatalog/owlapi/XMLCatalogIRIMapper.java

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the source code, looking for implementations of `OWLOntologyIRIMapper`. As far as I can tell, none of the implementations save their mappings to disk, much less in the Oasis XML Catalog format.

I'd be very happy to find out I am wrong, so please let me know if I am!

Comment: Not currently. Neat requirement though. https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/352